# how can I print out using 2 inputs from user and print out the numbers which is taken from user?

Tags: c#, for-loop

like 10 and 20 is taken. I,ll to print out even user give me 20 and 10. I mean to print out in both way negative and positive!

Console.WriteLine("Enter a number for looping!");
int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

```
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number for looping!");
        int input1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int i = input; i <= input1; i++)
        {              
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, this is what you want:

If user inputs `10` and `20`, you want program to print out **10, 11, 12, ... , 20**

If user inputs `20` and `10`, you want program to print out **20, 19, 18, ... , 10**

So the trick is to determine the "correct" for loop condition and increment for the 2 cases:

1. `input1` > `input` (ie, if user inputs `10` and then `20`)
2. `input1` <= `input` (ie, if user inputs `20` and then `10`)

To achieve that, you can do something like this:

```cs
Console.Write("Enter the starting number: ");
int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Enter the ending number: ");
int input1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

// new loop condition and increment
Func<int, bool> loopCondition = (i) => (input1 > input) ? i <= input1 : i >= input1;
int loopIncrement = (input1 > input) ? +1 : -1;

for (int i = input; loopCondition(i); i += loopIncrement)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

where the only new idea is:

```cs
// new loop condition and increment
Func<int, bool> loopCondition = (i) => (input1 > input) ? i <= input1 : i >= input1;
int loopIncrement = (input1 > input) ? +1 : -1;
```